# Cannot navigate to path using MemoryRouter while testing

Tags: react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I have followed the examples closely but I cannot get the **MemoryRouter** (is this how you are supposed to test route components?) to work with a test using jest and enzyme.

I would like to navigate to one of the routes, and have that reflected in my snapshot. The code below attempts to navigate using MemoryRouter to "/A" so I assume I would see `<div>A</div>`

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, MemoryRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Routing test', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/A"]}>
                    <div className={"Test"}>This is my Test Component and should not have any test specific code in it
                        <Router>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path={"/A"}>
                                    <div className={"A"}>A</div>
                                </Route>
                                <Route path={"/B"}>
                                    <div>B</div>
                                </Route>
                            </Switch>
                        </Router>
                    </div>
                </MemoryRouter>
        );
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.unmount();
    });

    it('matches snapshot', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(".Test")).toHaveLength(1); //this ok
        expect(wrapper.find(".A")).toHaveLength(1); //but this is not ok :( It should find  A
    });
});
```

Instead of seeing `<div>Test<div>A</div></div>` I just see `<div>Test</div>`

**NOTE:** My example is simplified into one class. My real world situation is that `<div>Test...</div>` is a seperate component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I figured it out.

Its very ugly but you need to create a `__mocks__` directory (In the first level of your project). `__mocks__` seems to be poorly documented but it seems to be a jest thing, and everything in here will be run when testing, and here you can add mock stubs for certain external libraries.

```
import React from 'react';

const reactRouterDom = require("react-router-dom")
reactRouterDom.BrowserRouter = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>

module.exports = reactRouterDom
```

My test file is the same as in my question (i think) :

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, MemoryRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Routing test', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/A']}>
                    <div className={"Test"}>This is my Test Component and should not have any test specific code in it
                        <Router>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path={"/A"}>
                                    <div className={"A"}>A</div>
                                </Route>
                                <Route path={"/B"}>
                                    <div>B</div>
                                </Route>
                            </Switch>
                        </Router>
                    </div>
                </MemoryRouter>
        );
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.unmount();
    });

    it('matches snapshot', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(".Test")).toHaveLength(1); //this ok
        expect(wrapper.find(".A")).toHaveLength(1); //but this is not ok :( It should find  A
    });
});
```

This works and my test is green! :)

**UPDATE :**

I think I got a bit confused because I was treating the Router like any other react component, when it actually is a top level component like redux `Provider`. Router should not be inside the `App` but outside the `App` like so (in an **index.js** file for example).

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <App/>,
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now when writing tests against App, I provide my own router such as **MemoryRouter**.

Comment: My follow up question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411156/cannot-test-redirecting-in-react-router-with-enzyme

Answer (score 3):

1. I can't find any proof of this but I always was under impression than you should use only one `<Router>` somewhere at the top of the tree and shouldn't nest them.
   So I've looked in the source code myself, and if I got it right, this is true. Because:

   1. *react-router* uses *Context API* to pass props down the hierarchy.
   2. From [*React* docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

      > [...] it will read the current context value from the **closest** matching `Provider` above it in the tree.
   3. `<Router>` is a `Provider` but not a `Consumer`, so it can't peek up props from a parent `<Router>`
2. When people advocate for tests they also mention that writing tests leads to a more testable code and a more testable code is cleaner. I wouldn't argue about this, I just wan't to note, that if you can write a testable code, then you also can write a non-testable one. And this looks like the case.

   So although you specifically say that

   > should not have any test specific code in it

   I would ague that, while you probably shouldn't use `createMemoryHistory` as @aquinq suggested, or put anything else specifically and **only for testing** purposes, you can and probably should **modify** your code to be more testable.

   You can:

   1. Move `<Router>` higher. You can even wrap the `<App>` with it - it's the simplest and a recommended way, although may not apply to your case. But still I don't see why can't you put `<div className={"Test"}>` inside the `<Router>` and not vice versa.
   2. In your tests you are not supposed to test third-party libraries, you supposed to test your own code, so you can extract this

      ```js
      <Switch>
        <Route path={"/A"}>
          <div className={"A"}>A</div>
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/B"}>
          <div>B</div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      ```

      part into a separate component and test it separately.
   3. Or if we combine these two: put `<div className={"Test"}>` inside the `<Router>`, extract `<div className={"Test"}>` into a separate component, write

      ```js
      wrapper = mount(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/A"]}>
          <TestDiv/>
        </MemoryRouter>
      )
      ```
   4. Also `createMemoryHistory` can be a useful feature on it's own. And some time in the future you'll find yourself using it. In that case @aquinq's answer will do.
3. But if you can't/don't want to modify your code at all. Then you can cheat a little and try this approach: [How to test a component with the <Router> tag inside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913963/how-to-test-a-component-with-the-router-tag-inside-of-it)

Comment: Please understand that <TestDiv> is the same as what I mean. I put the whole raw component in the test case in order to illustrate it better. interesting points, but If you can get my test to pass I will give you my bounty.

Comment: @OliverWatkins, So, I don't get it: you've answered your own question following the advice from the link I've posted. But as you leaved this comment and ":/" in your answer, and also I don't know how to figure out exact times of your answer and your comment... is the question answered or not?

Comment: And yes, I do understand that `<TestDiv>` is the component in question, and knowing that I've recommended to change it... or to use the advice from the link, which you did, that's also OK.

Comment: its half answered, i will give you half the bounty. The :/  means that i now have to figure out how to interactive navigate the routes in the test. thanks anyway

Comment: this is what I mean by the :/ - ie. i have a continuation question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411156/cannot-test-redirecting-in-react-router-with-enzyme

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing), if you use a regular `Router` in your test, you should pass a `history` prop to it

> While you may be tempted to stub out the router context yourself, we recommend you wrap your unit test in one of the Router components: the base `Router` with a history prop, or a `<StaticRouter>`, `<MemoryRouter>`, or `<BrowserRouter>`

Hope this will work. If not, maybe using a second `MemoryRouter` instead of `Router` will simply do the job.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean passing history to the router

Comment: It means you need to define your `Router`'s history

Comment: `import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';`

Comment: `<Router history={createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/'] })}>...</Router>`

Comment: In the above example I replaced the MemoryRouter with <Router history={createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/A'] })}> ..like you said, but my test still does not pass.

Comment: `MemoryRouter` is okay, I was talking about the `Router` two lines below.

Comment: thats part of my component that i wish to test and cannot be modified for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically Router will be outside of the app logic, and if you're using other `<Route>` tags, then you could use something like `<Switch>`, like this:

```html
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/blog">
        <BlogPost />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

**`MemoryRouter` actually *is* a `Router`, so it may be best to *replace* the "real" `Router` here.** You could split this into a separate component for easier testing.

According to the [source GitHub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md):

> The most common use-case for using the low-level `<Router>` is to
>   synchronize a custom history with a state management lib like Redux or Mobx. Note that this is not required to use state management libs alongside React Router, it's only for deep integration.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

From personal experience:

I have used an outer component (we called it "Root") that includes the `<Provider>` and `<Router>` components at the top level, then the `<App>` includes just the `<Switch>` and `<Route>` components.

`Root.jsx` returns:

```html
<Provider store={rootStore}>
  <Router history={rootHistory}>
    <App />
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

and `App.jsx` returns:

```html
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}>
  <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminPage}>
</Switch>
```

This allows the `App.test.jsx` to use:

```html
mount(
  <Provider store={fakeStore}>
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
      <App myProp={dummyProp} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```